# jetty web service giving 404 when invoked via reflection

Tags: java, reflection, jax-rs, jetty

Hello everyone i have a rest web service with embedded jetty server that is working completely fine when run as a standalone application but when i try to run the same web service via reflection my web service is giving me 404 error.No exceptions are thrown and the server is listening on the specified port. Need Help

Comment: Hello anybody who can answer?? i have  been banging my head for 4 hours

Comment: _"when i try to run the same web service via reflection"_ - What does that even _mean_? Please provide an [MCVE] for better help.

Comment: Means that when i try to call the method that starts the jetty server through reflection i.e. call it via method.invoke then my jetty server starts but when i try to access my web service it returns 404 error. There is no exception thrown

Comment: HI JayD do you find any answer?